# How to save a default python env for VSCode Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've started playing around with the new VSCode notebooks feature and I find one aspect of it particularly annoying.

I open my "jupyter_notebooks" directory the same way I would when using a typical jupyter server, except I open it in VSCode. And I click on a script to bring it into the editor.

However, when I go to run my first cell, it asks me which python environment I want to run it in. This happens every time I start running *any* script... this is particularly annoying because the "suggested" environment isn't the one that I always use.

Is there a way to set the default python env to a vscode workspace or something so that when I open that folder in vscode it just assumes which env I want to use and stops asking me?

This is an image of the menu that keeps popping up every time I want to run a new script.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use "Ctrl+Shift+P" and choose "Python:Select Interpreter"

[image]

Then reload window can work.

Comment: I never trust a man with a light theme -.0